# difference between /** and /* in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

probably it's a very stupid question, but I couldn't find anything on the internet.

What the difference between writing `<mvc:mapping path="/**"/>` and `<mvc:mapping path="/*"/>` in Spring?

Comment: I saw many example on the internet using /** when mapping, for example, a bean

Comment: do you mean spring-security? something like `<security:intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="ROLE_USER" />`

Comment: I'm merely guessing, but it could mean that sub-paths are also searched. Eg. /* will only find resources located in the root, while /** may find resources located in sub-directories of the root.

Comment: JohnnyAW maybe i saw it in pattern attibute and not in mapping, I'm no more sure where i saw it

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali I found another reference: `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/res/" />` in this case I think it's like @Henrik told, "**" means subdirectories included. As far as I know, spring uses ant-pattern you could search web for ant-file-patterns or something like that

Comment: Thank everybody. When /** is used in the pattern attribute means the same thing? 
For instance /user/** means that the valid urls are both /user/subFolder and /user/subFolder/subFolder/?

Comment: Yes.  It means that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is documented here:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison

Basically the Spring supports "Ant style globbing".  Thus `path="/*"` matches any URL in the `"/"` directory<sup>1</sup>, and `path="/**"` matches any URL in the entire directory tree.

The document primarily talks about request mappings specified using annotations, but wirings specified using XML have the same meaning.

---

<sup>1 - I am using the term "directory" loosely here.  Strictly speaking these are not directories at all.  But you know what I mean ...</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `/*` & `/**` is that the second matches the entire directory tree, including sub-directories, where as `/*` only matches at the level it's specified at.

`/**` url pattern is known as **ant path style syntax**